# Finding the Client ID for a RadGrid inside a RadLightBoxItem tag in a RadLightBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm trying to fetch the ClientID for a RadGrid control from client side using JavaScript so that I'll be able to bind data to this from the client side.

The RadGrid is present within the RadLightBox and needs to be populated on a button click event. The markup for LightBox looks something like this.

```
<telerik:RadLightBox ID="RadLightBox1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadLightBoxItem runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="lightbox_radgrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <MasterTableView>
                        <Columns>
                            <%-- Columns not shown here --%>
                        </Columns>
                    </MasterTableView>
                    <ClientSettings>
                        <ClientEvents OnCommand="window_radgrid_OnCommand" />
                    </ClientSettings>
                    <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" ShowUnGroupButton="true" />
                </telerik:RadGrid>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadLightBoxItem>
    </Items>
</telerik:RadLightBox>
```

This is the partial Javascript Code that I have written. I am able to find upto the RadLIghtBoxItem element but unable to fetch the RadGrid and it's clientID. This method is to be executed on success of a call to a web service to return the data.

```
function onSucessCallThis(result, userContext, methodName) {
            var radWindow = $find('<%= lightbox.ClientID %>');
            var LightBoxItems = radWindow.get_items();
            console.log(LightBoxItems);
            console.log(LightBoxItems.get_count());
            var item = LightBoxItems.getItem(0);
            console.log(item); //Able to fetch LightBoxItem
            var radGrid = item.FindControl("lightbox_radgrid"); //Doesn't work
        }
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to have a radGrid inside a radLightBox. There isn't many examples of this online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be easier for you to use a [RadWindow's ContentTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/getting-started/using-radwindow-as-controls-container). Something like:

```
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server" Modal="true">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server"></telerik:RadGrid>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </telerik:RadWindow>
        <script>
            function onSucessCallThis(result, userContext, methodName) {
                var wnd = $find("<%=RadWindow1.ClientID%>");
                if (!wnd.isVisible()) {
                    wnd.show();
                }
                var grid = $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID%>");
                var mtv = grid.get_masterTableView();
                mtv.set_dataSource(result);
                mtv.dataBind();
            }
        </script>
```

If you want to keep using a lightbox, review the [Get Client-side Reference to a Control Object](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/get-client-side-reference) article. The gist is that you can easily loop through the DOM, for example:

```
        <telerik:RadLightBox ID="RadLightBox1" runat="server">
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadLightBoxItem runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadGrid CssClass="gridInLightbox" runat="server" ID="lightbox_radgrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

                        </telerik:RadGrid>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:RadLightBoxItem>
            </Items>
        </telerik:RadLightBox>
        <script>
            function onSucessCallThis(result, userContext, methodName) {
                var lightbox = $find('<%= RadLightBox1.ClientID %>');

                //item objects do not refer the DOM so we can use the lightbox as a parent for the traversal
                var radGrid = $telerik.$(".gridInLightbox", lightbox.get_element())[0].control;//of course, add defensive checks
                alert(radGrid);
                var mtv = radGrid.get_masterTableView();
                mtv.set_dataSource(result);
                mtv.dataBind();
            }
        </script>
```